# How to join array in pipe

Tags: powershell, join, pipe

I wish to join the result from a pipe.

I tried using `-join`

```
PS> type .\bleh.log | where { $_ -match "foo"} | select -uniq | $_ -join ','
```

But that give me this error :/

> Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try this :

```
@(type .\bleh.log | where { $_ -match "foo"} | select -uniq) -join ","
```

You would need a `Foreach-Object` (alias `%`) after the last pipe to have the `$_` variable available but it wouldn't help since it holds a single cell value (for each loop iteration).

Comment: Isn't it possible to keep it as a one liner?

Comment: Answer edited. But if you need a real CSV file, there are dedicated cmdlets, like `Export-Csv`.

Comment: I just need to c/p the result, so the above is just what I want :)

Answer (score 0):

this code search the file for the characters "ya" and returns a unique list as an array.  It then takes the array elements and joins them into a string separated by a comma

```
 @(type requirements.txt | where {($_).Trim() -match "ya"} | select -Unique) -join ","
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative **PowerShell 6.2** and above comes with the [`Join-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/join-string?view=powershell-7.4) cmdlet:

```bash
Get-Content .\bleh.log |
    Where-Object { $_ -match 'foo' } |
    Select-Object -Unique |
    Join-String -Separator ','
```

A simple but not very reliably non-advanced function for Windows PowerShell could be:

```
function pipejoin {
    @($input) -join $args[0]
}

0..10 | pipejoin ','
```